# assign alias to an application for easy opening in terminal

Tags: terminal

Ok, so maybe I'm a little lazy. But is there a way to assign an alias to an application so that if I run a command in the terminal, I could use the alias instead of having to type the actual application's name...

example:

```
killall TextWrangler
```

would become...

```
killall tw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to alias `textwrangler` into `tw` for use with killall, but you can alias the full `killall` command this way :

`alias killalltw="killall TextWrangler"`

Something even shorter : `alias killtw="killall TextWrangler"`

You can't have any spaces in the alias' name.

For this to be persistent between Terminal sessions you will need to put this line into `~/bash_profile` file.